# Add the 3 login choices to a drop down on the "log In" link

Tags: feature-request, login

To log in, one has to:

1. Click "log in"
2. Be taken to a new page
3. On the page taken to, move the mouse from the very top where "log
   in" is, down/across to one of three options "Google/Facebook/Stack"
   and click
4. Fill in the form for login credentials

It's not particularly taxing, especially now we're logged in on all sites from a single login, however, I think it can be improved.

I suggest when hovering the "log in" link (top black bar) a drop down appears with the three options.

For example:

[image: new-login-option]

---

As per the above (mocked up) example image:

- Not all of the details from the login page should be in the dropdown.
  Only the three login options, clicking any of them would take you to
  the login form for the clicked option (as per the current login *page*
  does).
- The current login page will still remain and can be accessed by
  *clicking* the "log in" link (as it currently does), and (as outlined
  above) possibly a link in the new (proposed) dropdown.
- The "sign up" link won't be changed.

---

With the proposal, we'd:

1. Hover "log in"
2. Drop down appears
3. From within the same vicinity you hovered, select one of three options "Google/Facebook/Stack" from the (new) drop down
4. Fill in the form for login credentials

### Advantages

There is no longer a need for the login *page* to be loaded (can be if required), as it's replaced with a dropdown, which is quicker and less movement/clicks.
Adding the fact the form you eventually get to is auto focus, and my proposal being one click to get to the actual login form, the entire procedure will be much quicker and simpler.

Currently, by clicking "log in" we're taken to a *second page* and have to select something else *before* the actual login page.
However, logically most users expect to be taken to a "log in" page by their clicking "log in". 
My proposal fixes that as "hovering" the "log in" and selecting a login option all in the same area would take users straight to the *actual* login page from their first click, without a page in between.

---

This won't work on mobile devices (until tech advances) and will work as it currently does, but it's easier to navigate one's finger/thumb around a small screen so there'd be little gain anyway.

Comment: +1 Nice feature-request. Surely speeds up the login process. One question, upon clicking any of the choices in your current mock-up the username and password screen loads right in there i.e. within same drop-down, rt?

Comment: @HackerKarma No, the drop down is not to be "bulky" it just removes the need for the login *page* to be loaded and mouse navigated around. It would be untidy and likely troublesome to have openIds loading into a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks. May be someone might put a thinking cap and come up with another angle for the next part.

Comment: I think the original login page should still exist and be linked to, since some users may get confused using this and there will be link rot because of people linking to the original login page.

Comment: @awesomebing1 "*I think the original login page should still exist and be linked to*" I agree, as stated in my proposal "The current login page will still remain and can be accessed by clicking the "log in" link (as it currently does), and (as outlined above) possibly a link in the new (proposed) dropdown." Essentially, the drop down is just an addition